# SharePoint Server 2013 Service Pack 1 Installation Order

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, cumulative-update

I have a question regarding the order of SharePoint 2013 SP 1 installation.

My scenario goes as follows:

I installed SharePoint on a server as a single server farm where this server hosts Central Administration and also acts as a Web Front, let's assume this is server A , this server has Oct 2015 CU installed on it **without SP 1** (build number is 15.0.4763.1000).

Now I have another server (server B) that i want to join to this current farm and I already have installed SharePoint with SP 1 on this new server, so by running the configuration wizard on server B and after I retrieved the configuration database that I want to connect to, I was given a message saying that SP 1 is not installed on server A. So I started installing SP 1 on Server A, so my question is if I ran the configuration wizard after the installation of SP1 completes on server A, would it apply a new build number ? or there's no need to run the configuration wizard since the build version of Oct 2015 CU is ​15.0.4763.1000 while the SP 1 build version is 15.0.4569.1000 according to the reference below

http://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Regressions/SP2013SP1Mark2.aspx

Please share your ideas with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that is little strange for me, Because Oct 2015 CU required the SP1 installed on the Server. [it is perquisite.](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/stefan_gossner/2015/10/13/october-2015-cu-for-sharepoint-2013-is-available-for-download-2/)

But now, once you installed the SP1, you have to run the PSConfig Wizard in order to upgrade the Schema.

I am confused, may be it wont let you install the SharePoint, because your SharePoint is already on the higher number.

Comment: That's correct, as we all know SharePoint doesn't downgrade, it is always an upgrade, the strange thing is why did SharePoint ask me for older version of updates when I already have a higher build number on server A, which is Oct 2015 CU, and SP 1 build number is way lower than Oct 2015 CU's build numnber. It does not throw any message indicating that I'm on a higher build number, it accepts and proceeds with the installation..

Comment: If it won't ask u then you will be fine. Just install it and run the config wizard

Answer (score 1):

After every patch installation you do **you have to run SharePoint Configuration Wizard** either from the GUI och using PowerShell. Otherwise the Configuration Database isn't updated with the new patch.

Answer (score 0):

You have to run the configuration after every update on each server. If you have 3 servers, than you need to run the configuration wizard after installing the update on the servers on each server.